# Web Mapping - Satellite WMS

Tags: leaflet, wms

I need to find a free satellite WMS which is precise enough to reach a zoom level of 17 minimum. Precision is an important asset in my application.

I am working with Leaflet and I am aware of the existence of [this tool](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html). But I am actually looking for users stories about different tools to help me make a choice!

Big companies are not an option. They have changed their billing politics and screwed up my app.

Comment: Is OpenStreetMap an option? example https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WORLD_OSM_WMS

Comment: Contextualisation of sattelite imagery is really really a plus. For instance, trees coverage can improve my app greatly. Without any sufficient solution, i'll take OSM.

Comment: What's the coverage you need? A province, a country, worldwide?

Comment: Worldwide. Level provided by Bings Maps are good but clouds make the product "less beautiful".

Comment: [@Gilles-Antoine Nys](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/120552/gilles-antoine-nys) is it mandatory to deploy exactly WMS in your app? Maybe other web map services could be applicable, e.g. TMS Satellite by ESRI would be a nice choice I suppose.

Comment: I'll make tests. Thank you all for your prompt answers !

Comment: Just curious: which service did you use at the end ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://qms.nextgis.com/ - this is a great collection of various basemaps and other geodata sources.

Also read [FAQ](https://qms.nextgis.com/faq) and see [REST API](http://docs.nextgis.ru/qms_srv_dev/doc/api.html) documentation.

[image]

Comment: [@Dmitry Baryshnikov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9904/dmitry-baryshnikov) looks like this company does not any valid WMS with a worldwide satellite coverage.

Comment: @TarasDubrava you can add your own service. It's free.

Answer (score 1):

I give users choice I use ESRI, BING, GOOGLE, HERE, MAPBOX and NEARMAP for Satellite Imagery/Orthophotography.  Also OpenMapTiles for offline mbtiles. I would NOT use a WMS you want XYZ/TMS Tile Server or WMTS Tile Server.  Never use a OGC WMS unless that's the only option.  You want data that's tiled 256x256 pixel or multiples of that. Instead of a getmap request that's having to ask the server to build a PNG of that area. (you an speed up WMS with GeoWebCache and other tools that use Tiles to generate the image)  http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

Other Options include Planet and Digital Globe Satellite Imagery that's a subscription to use.  ESRI World Imagery Service is a good option. It does not have API Key as part of URL.
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png

If your in USA we have NAIP from USGS that's flown every year.  https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/NAIP

https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer

It's available as WMTS and WMS - see links below.
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS